# How can I parse SOAP web service in C#?

Tags: c#, soap

I'm new in C#,run simple SOAP web service, and that web service return me this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getBillsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://obrs/">
         <return>
            <errorID>7</errorID>
         </return>
      </ns2:getBillsResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My code is this for call that web service:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("certificate:" + certificate.GetName() + " sslPolicyErrors:" + sslPolicyErrors);
        return true;
    };
BankWebService.BillingServerService myService = new BankWebService.BillingServerService();
myService.getBill("1","2","3","4","5");
Console.WriteLine("ok");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I want to write this C# code for getBill output:

```
if (errorID == 7) then do something...
```

How can I implement that?

Comment: Could you post the definition of the return type of the `getBill` method as well?

Comment: `var bill = myService.getBill(...); if (bill.errorID == 7) { ... }`

Comment: If you are using WCF  (which, by the presence of `BillingServerService`), why do you need to be concerned with the underlying SOAP gobble-de-gook.  That generally is only an area of concern if your project is cross platform and/or there is a client (other than yours) that isn't using WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proxy code should already have a definition for that if your SOAP is anything to go by.

You should be able to do:

```
BankWebService.BillingServerService myService = new BankWebService.BillingServerService();
GetBillsResponse response =  // <----------------- NEW
       myService.getBill("1","2","3","4","5");
```

> I want to write this C# code for getBill output:
>   `if (errorID == 7) then do something...`

Once you have the `response` above you can simply:

```
var errorID = response.Return.ErrorID;
```

### Appendices

Plopping your SOAP into [xmltocsharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) I get

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="return")]
    public class Return {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="errorID")]
        public string ErrorID { get; set; }
    }

[XmlRoot(ElementName="getBillsResponse", Namespace="http://obrs/")]
public class GetBillsResponse {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="return")]
    public Return Return { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="ns2", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Ns2 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="getBillsResponse", Namespace="http://obrs/")]
    public GetBillsResponse GetBillsResponse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Envelope", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="S", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string S { get; set; }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a feature that parse the XML file for you:

- In `Solution Explorer`, right-click the name of the project that you
  want to add the service to, and then click Add `Service Reference`.
- In the Add Service Reference dialog box, click the `Advanced` button.
- In the Service Reference Settings dialog box, click Add `Web
  Reference`.
- In the `URL box`, enter the `URL` of the Web service to use.
- In the `Web services found at this URL box`, select the Web service to
  use.
- In the `Web reference name field`, enter a name that you will use in
  your code to access the selected Web service programmatically.
- Click `Add Reference`.

using tutorial above allows the visual studio to add the webservice into your project, and anytime you need it, you just call the webservice(Whatever you put in the web reference name field) and create an object from it (Create an instance from it), and you can easily use its methods like below:

```
using(WebService.MainClass obj = new WebService.MainClass())
{
    int id = obj.GetId("Method Inputs"); 
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Whilst a jolly good answer, considering OP already has a `BankWebService.BillingServerService` it's quite possible he/she has already performed a add service reference

Comment: @MickyD yeah.. i thought he had problem with parsing, was bit unclear there for me, great job with your answer tho voted :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse the XML to extract the field you need. There are many ways to do this. One way is to use XmlDocument();

For example for the XML you gave and the required field;

```
 private static int ParseErrorIdField(string xml)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        var errorIdField = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(name(),'errorID')]");
        if (errorIdField == null)
        {
            //couldn't find field in xml
            //return parsing error
            return -1;
        }

        int errorId;

        if (!int.TryParse(errorIdField.InnerText, out errorId))
        {
            //Could not convert field to integer
            //raise error
            return -1;
        }

        return errorId;
    }
```

Comment: Why the down vote? The OP didn't specify only they only wanted a WCF way of parsing XML. I did also mention there are many ways of parsing XML and that the way I suggested was just one way

Comment: What are the components of WCF doing? They are parsing. In order to get the value from the XML something has to parse. So I'd say you do need to parse. How you go about thatis up to you, and no specific restrictions were stated.